# Scala Amazon S3 streaming object

Tags: scala, performance, amazon-s3

I am looking to use to Scala to get faster performance in accessing and downloading a Amazon S3 file. The file comes in as a InputStream and it is large (over 30 million rows).

I have tried this in python (pandas), but it is too slow. I am hoping to increase the speed with Scala.

So far I am doing this, but it is too slow. Have I encountered a bottle neck in the stream in that I cannot access data from the stream any faster than what I have with the code below?

```
val obj = amazonS3Client.getObject(bucket_name, file_name)
val reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(obj.getObjectContent()))

while(line != null) {
list_of_lines = list_of_lines ::: List(line)
line = reader.readLine
}
```

I'm looking for serious speed improvement compared to the above approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your performance bottleneck is appending to a (linked) `List` in that loop:

```scala
list_of_lines = list_of_lines ::: List(line)
```

With 30 million lines, it should take a few hundred trillion times longer to process all the lines than it takes to process one line.  If the first iteration of that loop is 1ns, then this should take somewhere around 15 minutes to execute.

Switching to prepending to the `List` and then reversing at the end should improve the speed of your loop by a factor of more than a million:

```scala
while(line != null) {
  list_of_lines = line :: list_of_lines
  line = reader.readLine
}
list_of_lines = list_of_lines.reverse
```

`List` is also notoriously memory-inefficient, so for this many elements, it's may also be worth doing something like this (which is also more idiomatic Scala):

```scala
import scala.io.{ Codec, Source }

val obj = amazonS3Client.getObject(bucket_name, file_name)

val source = Source.fromInputStream(obj.getObjectContent())(Codec.defaultCharsetCodec)

val lines = source.getLines().toVector
```

`Vector` being more memory-efficient than `List` should dramatically reduce GC thrashing.

Comment: It may be good to also mention that if the object is too big it may be better to stream it using **AkkaStreams**, **fs2**, **ZIO**, etc.

Comment: so i went through the loop without doing the list operation and just printing a count variable and it was still far too slow. i am thinking by general approach of using a loop is the real performance bottleneck. does that sound right? @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: @H_1317 I mean, I doubt the loop alone is slow if you are not accumulating the data. So maybe using the **SDK v2** as mentioned in the other answer may improve the situation; btw, still is probably that the streaming libraries mentioned above would have modules that use the **SDK v2** under the hood and the `Stream` data type may be easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve better performance is using the `TransferManager` provided by the AWS Java SDKs. It's a high level file transfer manager that will automatically parallelise downloads. I'd recommend using [SDK v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/transfer-manager.html), but the same can be done with [SDK v1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-transfermanager.html#transfermanager-download-file). Though, be aware, SDK v1 comes with limitations and only multipart files can be downloaded in parallel.

You need the following dependency (assuming you are using `sbt` with `Scala`). But note, there's no benefit of using `Scala` over `Java` with the `TransferManager`.

```
libraryDependencies += "software.amazon.awssdk" % "s3-transfer-manager" % "2.17.243-PREVIEW"
```

Example (Java):

```
S3TransferManager transferManager = S3TransferManager.create();
FileDownload download = 
    transferManager.downloadFile(b -> b.destination(Paths.get("myFile.txt"))
                                       .getObjectRequest(req -> req.bucket("bucket").key("key")));
download.completionFuture().join();
```

I recommend reading more on the topic here: [Introducing Amazon S3 Transfer Manager in the AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-amazon-s3-transfer-manager-in-the-aws-sdk-for-java-2-x/)